# Length of an array in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, jboss, command

I am writing a shell script. I need to capture the array length. Array is the output of one command. I am trying it as : N=0

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep java| egrep "tomcat|jboss|JBoss" | awk '{print $2}') ;
do
array[$N]="$pid"

echo "${#array[@]}"
arraylen=${#array[@]}
if [ $arraylen=1 ]
then
(sleep $sleepTime;jstack ${array[$0]} > jStack_${array[$0]}_prod.txt & )

elif [$arraylen =2]
then
(sleep $sleepTime;jstack ${array[$0]} > jStack_${array[$0]_prod.txt & )
(sleep 10;jstack ${array[$1]} > jStack_${array[$1]}_prod.txt & )

elif [$arraylen =3]
then
(sleep $sleepTime;jstack ${array[$0]} >  jStack_${array[$0]}_prod.txt & )
(sleep 10;jstack ${array[$1]} > jStack_${array[$1]}_prod.txt & )
(sleep 10;jstack ${array[$2]} > jStack_${array[$2]}_prod.txt & )

done
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this script in BASH:

```
array=( $(ps -ef | awk '/java/ && /tomcat|jboss|JBoss/{print $2}') )
echo "${#array[@]}"
```

---

**EDIT:** If you want to run a loop you can do:

```
array=()
while read -r p; do
   echo "processing: $p"
   array+=("$p")
done < <(ps -ef | awk '/java/ && /tomcat|jboss|JBoss/{print $2}')
echo "${#array[@]}"
```

Comment: Yes, your code is helping me to retrieve the array length. But i need to use the for loop as I have to run some other commands inside the for loop after getting the array length. Please refer my edited code block in my original question.

Comment: ok check my **EDIT** section for looping through various results.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with your script is that you never incremented the index "N".The following script may solve your problem.

```
N=0
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep java| egrep "tomcat|jboss|JBoss" | awk '{print $2}') ;
do
  array[$N]="$pid"
  N=$(( N + 1 ))

done
echo "${#array[@]}"
```